# How to install Windows as a second OS?

Tags: windows

I've installed Xubuntu 14 on my laptop. But now the laptop cannot detect the windows installation disc. When I put in the disc and restart, nothing changed; it still went directly into Xubuntu without any option. I'm sure nothing is wrong with BIOS since I have checked it many times. When I insert Ubuntu installation disc and restart, it shows the options perfectly. What should I do in order to install windows on my laptop?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot This question gets asked almost every day on this site.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  This person is specifically having trouble booting from a CD.

Comment: The link to our canonical "how to install windows" question is valid.  Anything additional about specific Windows issues and possible hardware issues are not in scope for this site - superuser.com would be more appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specifically configure your BIOS to boot from the CD drive.

How to do this varies according to your system.  Sometimes F12 during initial boot is all that is required to bring up a menu, from which you choose the CD drive as the boot drive.

Other times you'll need to go into the regular BIOS setup (using a key like F2, esc or del) and find where the boot devices are configured.  You may have to both enable the CD drive as a boot drive, *and* ensure that it is higher in the boot priority than your hard drive.

After your OS is installed if you have no other reason to boot from CD you can then un-do whatever settings you changed.

Comment: BIOS is all set. CD drive first, then USB, and local drive is the last one...